# How to search a gray scale image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image]I have 10 gray scale images<2559*3105>. These images are taken from X-ray reflectivity measurement. Each image has two spots except first, showing intensity of X-ray. First image has one highest intensity spot. From second to tenth image each has two spots first one is same as in the first image but second one differs with respect to the location and intensity value. I want to search and crop these spots. The problem is when i apply a condition that find() maximum intensity point in the image, it always points to the spot which is common in all images.

Comment: can you post a sample image?  how much do you want to crop? do you have the image processing toolbox?  your question is not so well defined...

Comment: In this image the common spot is in circle and the second spot which is different in other images is below the circle. Now i want to crop that second spot from all images by searching maximum intensity pixel in the image except the circle. How can i do this?

Comment: you can threshold and use `bwlabel`...  I'll answer you later if you wont get an answer in the next 12 hours...

Answer (score 1):

here's some basic image processing code that allows you to select the indices of the spots

```
%# read the image 
im=rgb2gray(imread('a.jpg'));

%# select only relevant area

d=im(5:545,5:660);

%# set a threshold and filter
thres = (max([min(max(d,[],1))  min(max(d,[],2))])) ;
filt=fspecial('gaussian', 7,1);

% reduce noise threshold and smooth the image
d=medfilt2(d);
d=d.*uint8(d>thres);
d=conv2(double(d),filt,'same') ;
d=d.*(d>thres);

% find coonected objets 1
L = bwlabel(d);

%#  or also
CC = bwconncomp(d);
```

Both `L` and `CC` have information about the indices of the 2 blobs, so you can now select only that part of the image using them